# Best practise for injecting custom modules [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection

Suppose there are 3 modules

1. M1
2. M2
3. M3

M3 is dependent on M2 and M1.    Now Server A1 is already using M2. A1 needs to use M3. 
Problem is M2 is loading twice when server is running. 
What is best/effiecient practise for dependency injection in node servers.

Comment: Reading this article https://blog.redradix.com/an-architecture-for-complex-node-js-apps-with-dependency-injection/    .Is there better solution than this , ?